# I am creating a simple reverse string android application, please confirm me whether the way I'm proceeding is right or not

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.desktop.mirror;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public EditText a;
public String entereda;
public EditText b;
public String enteredb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void OnClick(View v){
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_text);
    b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_text);
    if(boolean entereda){
        Intent i = new (this, reverseactivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = menu.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menu);
}
```

I'm new to both Java and Android, so I can not be more specific.
My question might be a silly one, since it's a simple one to be implemented in Java, but coming to implementation on Android, i'm struggling a lot with the code.

Comment: This question doesn't really fit the StackOverflow format.  The guidelines discourage questions that ask whether code works or does not work, or that involve debugging your code.  You can read about what questions to avoid asking here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.  If you have a *specific* question that proceeds from your attempt to run code you've written, please post it here.  We're happy to help.

Comment: you can ask about the approach with "Java" or how to use an `Activity` or whether something more specific makes sense. There are far too many ways to do any one particular task to judge whether you are "doing it right"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try out this minimal code (2 lines, excluding the `Sysyem.out.println()`) :

```
// The big works ;)
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("Test!");
buffer.reverse();

// Test it out
System.out.println(buffer); // .toString());
```

Output:

```
!tseT
```

Required import:

```
java.lang.StringBuffer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void OnClick (View v){
    a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_text);
    b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second_text);

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(100);


    String entereda = a.getText().toString();

    int str_len = entereda.length();

    for (int i = (str_len - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(entereda.charAt(i));
        s.append(entereda.charAt(i));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with android either, but to reverse strings:

```
public static String reverse(String toReverse) {
    Stack<Character> letters = new Stack<Character>();
    for(char c:toReverse.toCharArray()) {
        letters.push(c);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(!letters.empty()) {
        sb.append(letters.pop());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And just have the result show up using a Thread and setting the result to the value of where you want it to go.

**Java isn't different from Android, just Android has built-in GUI capabilities.**

And how do you get the code to show up in java?